# Audio output to input

Tags: sound, input, output

The audio output port on my laptop just broke and I can no longer use it for my headphones. Does anyone know of a way I can route the sound output through the input instead?

Comment: I think this might be useful:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/225017/how-do-i-change-which-audio-jacks-are-used-for-input-and-output

Answer (score 1):

You can try [HDA-analyzer](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/HDA_Analyzer)

The HDA analyzer tool provides a graphical interface to access the raw HD-audio control, based on pyGTK2 binding. The program gives you an easy-to-use GUI stuff for showing the widget information and adjusting the amp values, as well as the proc-compatible output.

This tool can parse also proc files (/proc/asound/card#/codec*) and output from alsa-info.sh script and monitor mode

Open this command on terminal:

1. Get the basic run.py script:

   ```
   wget -O run.py http://www.alsa-project.org/hda-analyzer.py
   ```
2. Quick run:

   ```
   python run.py
   ```
3. Quick help:

   ```
   python run.py --help
   ```
4. Quick alsa-info.sh file analyzer:

   ```
   python run.py /tmp/alsa-info.txt
   ```
5. Quick monitor mode:

   ```
   python run.py --monitor
   ```

Comment: Uh... wonderful copy&paste job. I looked at the tool and there would be some more explanation needed to answer the question. Would you be so kind, please?