# Python script to change the jack from input to output does not work in 13.04

Tags: sound, python, sudo, jack

To change the jack from input to output for any computer or laptop I followed this question:

[How do I change which audio jacks are used for input and output?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225017/how-do-i-change-which-audio-jacks-are-used-for-input-and-output)

But the Python script does not work. This is the message I get:

```
$ sudo python run.py
Using temporary directory: /dev/shm/hda-analyzer
You may remove this directory when finished or if you like to
download the most recent copy of hda-analyzer tool.
Downloading file hda_analyzer.py
Downloading file hda_guilib.py
Downloading file hda_codec.py
Downloading file hda_proc.py
Downloading file hda_graph.py
Downloading file hda_mixer.py
Downloaded all files, executing hda_analyzer.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/dev/shm/hda-analyzer/hda_analyzer.py", line 36, in <module>
    from hda_codec import HDACodec, HDA_card_list, HDA_Exporter_pyscript, \
  File "/run/shm/hda-analyzer/hda_codec.py", line 330
    self.reread()
       ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: This is clearly a bug in the script from the ALSA project and should be reported there. As such this question is off topic here (see[FAQ]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed all the basic problems and manged to open the GUI.

`sudo wget -O /run/shm/hda-analyzer/hda_codec.py http://ideone.com/plain/I0Tje0`

And then do

`sudo python run.py`

Comment: Oops. I ll try and give the diff output

Comment: Uploaded it to ideone :)

Comment: Hope this is an unbreakable link then ;)

Comment: Yup. Ideone is an awesome website. Please try that, if you haven’t yet.

Comment: how do i save it

Comment: The first command will save the file in respective place (/run/shm/hda-analyzer/hda_codec.py).