# No sounds after upgrade

Tags: sound

I upgraded my Ubuntu to 13.10 and now I can't hear any sounds.

I checked on `alsamixer` that voices are on. For example, I can't hear any Youtube videos.

Comment: Not sure why someone protected this question - it an ongoing issue affecting ***MANY*** people - point of StackExchange is to float to top in-demand questions/answers, not shunt out inputs

Comment: This question is a mess. It offers no details about what could be get wrong, the accepted answer is "wait" until upstream fix their stuff. @ScottStensland I'm not even sure why this wasn't closed in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

I also lost my sound when upgrading to 13.10.

To fix it, I ran this in Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Did a restart, and everything was working perfectly.

Comment: I tried this but it won't solve the problem on my computer.

Comment: did not work for me either

Comment: i tried this and the other answer i commented upon.  worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I got mine working when I looked at [this document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iTlJ8BfqXUjaHO__TEdlkvuqB1WLOkGaudngc5SFLMI):

The issue was that I needed to add some permissions to my user.  Easy to tell if that's the fix because `aplay -l` will say no soundcards but `sudo aplay -l` lists some.  This was my fix:

```
sudo usermod -aG audio,video,pulse,pulse-access frew
```

Comment: i tried this and the other answer i commented upon.  worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me [How do I change which audio jacks are used for input and output?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225017/how-do-i-change-which-audio-jacks-are-used-for-input-and-output)
or make this in to a `hda-mods.py` and put it in `/etc` folder because on `sudo python run.py` all the sound muted just unmute the sound then save it

If you want to keep your changes permanently, don't close HDA Analyzer yet. Instead, click "Exp" (Export) at the bottom-left and use Save As to write the python script to a file. Now copy that file to something like `/etc/hda-mods.py` and edit `/etc/rc.local` as root (e.g. using `gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local`) and add the line `python /etc/hda-mods.py` right before the exit 0 line, then save it and reboot. Your changes should survive.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import struct
from fcntl import ioctl

def __ioctl_val(val):
  # workaround for OverFlow bug in python 2.4
  if val & 0x80000000:
    return -((val^0xffffffff)+1)
  return val

IOCTL_INFO = __ioctl_val(0x80dc4801)
IOCTL_PVERSION = __ioctl_val(0x80044810)
IOCTL_VERB_WRITE = __ioctl_val(0xc0084811)

def set(nid, verb, param):
  verb = (nid << 24) | (verb << 8) | param
  res = ioctl(FD, IOCTL_VERB_WRITE, struct.pack('II', verb, 0))  

FD = os.open("/dev/snd/hwC0D0", os.O_RDONLY)
info = struct.pack('Ii64s80si64s', 0, 0, '', '', 0, '')
res = ioctl(FD, IOCTL_INFO, info)
name = struct.unpack('Ii64s80si64s', res)[3]
if not name.startswith('HDA Codec'):
  raise IOError, "unknown HDA hwdep interface"
res = ioctl(FD, IOCTL_PVERSION, struct.pack('I', 0))
version = struct.unpack('I', res)
if version < 0x00010000:    # 1.0.0
  raise IOError, "unknown HDA hwdep version"

# initialization sequence starts here...

set(0x0e, 0x300, 0x6080) # 0x0e036080 (SET_AMP_GAIN_MUTE)

os.close(FD)
```