# Audio output not working on Thinkpad pro dock with X270

Tags: sound, thinkpad

I have a thinkpad X270 that I use on a docking station "Lenovo thinkpad pro dock". Jack output is working correctly on the laptop port, but I get nothing out when I connect headphones to the dock port. This seems to be related to a known bug, mentioned in this question:
[ThinkPad T440p docking station: no sound on external speakers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483174)

But it also says that the bug should have been fixed in newer kernels, and this bug dates back from 2014... I am running the LTS Ubuntu 16.04.

Anyway, the workaround described in the solution to the above question did not solve my problem (adding the codecs in /lib/firmware/ and then adding a line in /etc/modprobe.d/hda-intel.conf).

Does someone has any clue about the status of this bug for Ubuntu 16.04 and a Thinkpad X270?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been fixed upstream in [kernel 4.15.8](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195161).

I'm also running LTS 16.04 on my x270, after installing `linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04-edge`, this dock (`40A20170US`) audio-out started working \o/:

```
$ uname -a
Linux jjo-x270 4.15.0-23-generic #25~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 25 04:50:20 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

FFR `alsa-info.sh` uploaded to http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=764e566e30923ca8b67ad7e11be4a9ae734759c7