# How do I map the audio motherboard jack to some other jack?

Tags: sound, realtek, audio-jack

I've tried the hda-jack-retask tool, but I couldn't get it working quite right, and the program itself seems quite buggy. On Windows, it's possible to do this on the Realtek audio panel, and I wanted to do the same on Linux.

I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 15.10, with kernel 4.4.2. My motherboard is a Gigabyte P35-DS3L (rev 2.0), and I am using the onboard audio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem by myself with the hda-jack-retask tool.

I had to uncomment and set `autospawn = no` on `/etc/pulse/client.conf`, and do `killall pulseaudio` next. Only then did the changes I applied on hda-jack-retask work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help [3 year ago question](https://askubuntu.com/a/225594/493231)

If not here is a project that suppose to do the same as hda-jack-retask
[JACK](http://www.jackaudio.org/downloads/)

Comment: And I found a PPA for hda-jack-retask [HD audio related stuff](https://launchpad.net/~diwic/+archive/ubuntu/hda)