# Mic problems with Analogue Stereo Duplex

Tags: sound, 16.04, alsa, pavucontrol

Ubuntu Unity 16.04 Toshiba Chromebook 2

I'm trying to get my mic working, either external or internal.

There is no input sound available within settings and no internal external mic option within alsamixer capture panel, only within the playback panel.

There is no feedback within pavucontrol and I've completely come to a dead end to fix it.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1420988, you should add the line `options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi` in the file called `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` (or create the file if it doen't exist). You might need to adjust your model. I have seen `model=intel` a lot. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1043568 and https://docs.slackware.com/howtos:hardware:audio_and_snd-hda-intel can help you out.

Did the trick for me partly. Also, `hdajackretask` is your friend: I needed to set Pin `0x18` to `microphone`. Or, via ->advanced, to `headphones` (thus the contact works for both)

For configuration, the standard `pavucontrol` and `gnome-alsa-mixer` will be helpful.