# I want to use the blue jack as my headphones

Tags: pulseaudio

I already did everything that is said in [this answer that uses hda-analyser](https://askubuntu.com/a/225594/355957) but it is an old answer and it doesn't work for me, not even temporally when I change the in>out in hda-analyser.

I am on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

edit:I used the command

pulseaudio -D

and I got

E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to type this command: `pulseaudio -D`

Then open your bashrc , type `Leafpad .bashrc` scroll down and write:

```
pulseaudio-d
clear
```